# Does creating a bean degrades the performance compared to creating a new object of that class every time i need?

Tags: performance, object, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-bean

I am writing into a database using spring batch . I have created `JdbcBatchItemWriter` as a bean but inside this I am also creating a new object of `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider()` .

I wonder if every time a new object will be created for `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider()` ?

Is it going to be one object since I have declared it in a bean though my bean is returning object of a type `JdbcBatchItemWriter` ?

**Approach 1**

```
  @Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<CdsData> cdsWriter(@Qualifier("MySql") final DataSource dataSource)
{
    JdbcBatchItemWriter jdbcCdsWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter();
    jdbcCdsWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcCdsWriter.setSql(mySqlCdsdataSql);
    jdbcCdsWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider());
    return jdbcCdsWriter;
}
```

Just to compare the performance , I created a separate bean for `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider()` to ensure I am not creating a new object every time. To my surprise what I am seeing with below code , it is taking more time now to insert into a database . Could anyone please explain why approach 2 has degraded the performance ?

Is it fine to go with approach 1 because I believe it is creating object for `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` every time.

**Approach 2**

```
      @Bean
public BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider sqlparmeter()
{
    BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider beanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider =
            new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider();
    return beanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
}



   @Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<CdsData> cdsWriter(@Qualifier("MySql") final DataSource dataSource)
                                             ,BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider beanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider)
{
    JdbcBatchItemWriter jdbcCdsWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter();
    jdbcCdsWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcCdsWriter.setSql(mySqlCdsdataSql);
    jdbcCdsWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(beanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider);
    return jdbcCdsWriter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this optimization. ItemWriter is instantiated just once (when the job starts).

I am sure that the bottleneck is actually somewhere else. You are using JDBC - IO is very slow, so there is no point in optimizing objects creating.

If you really need to optimize this, I suggest you use a tool like VisualVM.

Comment: Are you saying there is going to be one object for BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider() although my bean JdbcBatchItemWriter is returning an object of  JdbcBatchItemWriter ?

Comment: I suppose yes. Please, try to debug it.